# Solving this matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, matrix-equations, parametric

Suppose $\mathbf{c}(\theta)$ is a known parametric circular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

How could we go about solving the following for $\theta$?

$$(\mathbf{x}-A\mathbf{c}(\theta))^TBA\mathbf{c}'(\theta)=0$$

where

- $B=(I-\frac{1_{4\times4}D}{Tr(D)})^TD$
- $D\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times4}$ is a diagonal matrix
- $1_{4\times4}$ is a matrix with all elements equal to 1.
- $A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1\\1&1&-1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: By "parameric circular curve in $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $" do you mean that $\ \mathbf{c}\ $ has the form
$$
\mathbf{c}(\theta)=\mathbf{c}_0+r\cos\theta\ \mathbf{u}+r\sin\theta\,\mathbf{u}_\perp
$$
where $\  \mathbf{c}_0\in\mathbb{R}^3\ $ and $\ \mathbf{u}\ $ and $\ \mathbf{u}_\perp\ $ are orthogonal unit vectors in $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $?  If so shouldn't it be "parameric circular curve in $\ \mathbb{R}^{\color{red}4}\ $" , since $\ A\ $ is a $\ 4\times4\ $ matrix?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Yes you correctly interpret what I mean. Note that $A$ is a $4\times3$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks.  As it happens, I'm due for what appears to be a much needed eye test tomorrow.